# xml based Navigation

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, c#-4.0

I have a following xml -

```
   <Menu>
     <submenu1>
      <subsubmenu1>
         <subsubsubmenu1>
           <item> Name </item>
           <itemvalue> Value </itemvalue>
         </subsubsubmenu1>
       </subsubmenu1>
     </submenu1>
     <submenu2>
      <subsubmenu2>
         <subsubsubmenu2_0>
           <item> Name </item>
           <itemvalue> Value </itemvalue>
         </subsubsubmenu2_0>
         <subsubsubmenu2_1>
           <item> Name </item>
           <itemvalue> Value </itemvalue>
         </subsubsubmenu2_1>
       </subsubmenu2>
     </submenu2>
   </Menu>
```

On button click, I want to display on label first 'Menu' , on clicking again 'Submenu' , on clicking again 'Subsubmenu' and so on.
What data structure / collection can be used? How can it be achieved?

Comment: Where did you get that XML?

Comment: its an xml given by architect to build upon...

Comment: is it dynamic XML or there is only going to be till subsubsubMenu ?

Comment: it is dynamic xml. can go further inner.

Comment: Please help on this.